# Creating a Table caption with csvsimple package using \csvautotabular{}

Tags: csvsimple

I have the following CSV `dow_distribution.csv` file:

```
DoW,ANZ Vol.,CBA Vol.,MQG Vol.,NAB Vol.,WBC Vol.,AORD Vol.,Total Vol.
Monday,3.63,1.93,0.88,3.14,3.56,457.56,470.7
Tuesday,4.11,2.12,0.92,3.64,4.07,520.05,534.92
Wednesday,4.36,2.26,1.02,3.86,4.3,543.45,559.25
Thursday,4.56,2.46,1.07,4.22,4.44,547.04,563.79
Friday,2.47,1.36,0.63,2.22,2.33,292.65,301.67
Saturday,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Sunday,1.58,0.86,0.35,1.4,1.56,194.2,199.96
```

I want to create a multiple bar charts from this csv file.
I've come across the [`csvsimple` package](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf), which makes creating tables from CSV files very easy.

**Question:**

I can't seem to find a way of creating a caption when I use this package, how can I create a caption for a table created by using `\csvautotabular{}`?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular{dow_distribution.csv}

\end{document}
```

**Desired Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you would any other table, place the `\csvautotabular` in a `table` environment and add a `\caption`. I think I'd suggest loading the `booktabs` package and using `\csvautobooktabular` by the way.

To specify different column types, I think you have to use `\csvreader`, which is a bit more work. I couldn't make it work with `\csvautotabular` at least, though it's possible I just did something wrong.

By the way, `14` is not a valid option to the documentclass (neither is `14pt`), so you get a warning about an "unused global option" if you don't remove it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{booktabs} % added
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\csvreader[
  tabular=|r*{7}{|c}|,
  table head= \hline DoW & ANZ Vol. & CBA Vol. & MQG Vol. & NAB Vol. & WBC Vol. & AORD Vol. & Total Vol. \\ \hline,
  late after last line=\\\hline,
]{dow_distribution.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii}

\caption{Foo}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\csvautobooktabular{dow_distribution.csv}
\caption{Foo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would one modify the borders of the table to look like the one in my question (ie include vertical lines)? Also how would one make the whole table center aligned with the exception of the days of the week beinf right aligned? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @3kstc The lack of vertical lines comes from using `\csvautobooktabular` instead of `\csvautotabular`. Just remove the `book` and you're back to what you had, though I think it looks much better without the vertical lines.

Comment: @3kstc Don't know offhand how to change the alignment of the columns, will have to browse the manual a bit.